# creating a multi-dimensional numpy array where each dimension of the array is of length L

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm looking to create a numpy array of d dimensions, where each dimension is of length `n`.

For example:

`np.zeros((5,2))`, will give me a 5-row, 2-column array of zeros.  What I'm looking for is a 5x5 array.  Now I know I can simply do `np.zeros((5,5))`, but my goal is to generate the array dynamically:

```py
dims = 4
elem_length = 10
#generate the array
#results in a 10x10x10x10 numpy array
```

Another option is to create single-dimensional tuples and join them all:

```py
shp = ()
for i in range(dims):
   shp = shp + (elem_length,)
new_arr = np.zeros(shp)
```

But that's not python-y at all. Is there a better way?

Comment: `(10,)*4` should produce `(10,10,10,10)`.  But don't be too entusiastic.  Such arrys get awfully big.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about `numpy` way to generate a `dxdxdx...` array, but if you wanted to generate the shape tuple you could try list comprehension.

EX:

```py
shape_list = [elem_length for _ in range(dims)]
shape_tuple = tuple(shape_list)
print(shape_tuple)
>> (elem_length, elem_length, elem_length)

dn_arr = np.zeros(shape_tuple)
print(dn_arr.shape)
>> (elem_length, elem_length, elem_length)
```

Comment: Thanks!  This works.  I'm new to python and didn't realize the tuple() function existed.